# Speeding up cloth simulation

Tags: cloth-simulation

Is there any ways to speed up cloth simulation? I have fiddled with multi-threading count but maybe I am missing an obvious option. Is GPU cloth simulation a thing?

Comment: Hi and welcome to BlenderSE. Currently there is no GPU acceleration for Blender Physics. Could you go a little deeper into your model setup?

Comment: Look here. There is no big change this concerns cloth simulation, but you can try :-)  https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.78/More_Features

Comment: @metaphor_set Well, I have a high poly figure rigged, and a high poly shirt over the model, I was hoping to have the shirt simulated as cloth, but I have found that making the whole shirt cloth is not working out so well. I have 2 main issues, the cloth sitting too far from the mesh even with the distance set to .001, and secondly, the cloth on his arms rides up the length of his arm, making the long sleeve shirt into a very jagged 3/4 length shirt. Figure is in T pose and the shirt vertex count is about 30k. Is it logical to simulate the entire shirt or should I be doing something different?

Answer (score 3):

You can transfer lower-poly simulation into high-poly mesh with [Surface Deform modifier](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.79/Modelling). Lower-poly or mid-poly sim is also easier to control and weight-paint.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't already have a lot of detail on the shirt you could try using a low poly and choose a frame you like, then raise the poly count and add the details afterwards.you can also try lowering the simulation speed and quality which can help lower the time taken to simulate without making it unstable like just lowering the quality might.

for the shirt rolling up the arms when you simulate, try lowering the outer face thickness of the character, if you do this the cloth will collide closer to the mesh but is more likely to clip through so raising the the simulation quality and lowering sim speed will probably be necessary to get the result you want.